# GraphQL - Field "x" of type "[User]" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "x{ ... }

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to get the following simple query:

```
{duel{id, players}}
```

and I get the following error:

```
Field "players" of type "[User]" must have a selection of subfields. Did you mean "players { ... }
```

My Duel type structure:

```
const DuelType = new ObjectType({
  name: 'Duel',
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: new NonNull(ID) },
    round_id: { type: IntType },
    status: { type: StringType },
    turn_of_user_id: { type: IntType },
    winner: { type: StringType },
    players: { type: new GraphQLList(UserType) },
  }),
});
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must specify the fields in `UserType` you want to get for each item in the `players` list. Assuming `UserType` has a `name` field, this example could work for your use case:

```
{
  duel {
    id,
    players {
      name
    }
  }
}
```